# Comparison of classes themselves (types), how they work?

Tags: python, oop, cpython, metaclass

I'm trying to figure out how the comparison `type(v) == int` works in Python (and why should I use `is` instead of `==` in this case), for what I've been reading about classes and metaclasses in Python, but still I don't know exactly what happens (what is being compare exactly) when you compare two classes (classes themselves, not instances). I supposed that the answer would be in the definition of the equals method of the `type` metaclass, which is the class of `int` and `type(v)`, so I would like to see the source code of that definition but I haven't been able to find it yet.

So, please, could anybody point me to the exact definition of the method or explain to me what is happening under the hood when I compare two classes (two instances of the `type` metaclass/class)?

Comment: Classes are objects, just like class instances.  `3` is an instance of the `int` class.  `int` is an instance of class `type`.  They can be compared just like any other object.

Comment: Classes inherit their `__eq__` implemention from `object` I'm pretty sure, which does equality by identity. Using `is` to compare is more of a convention than a necessity

Comment: And missing in your comments: actually unless one has a very specific need, class comparison should always be done through calling `isinstance` (for instances) and  `issubclass` for classes: these correctly take into account subclassing (d'oh) and can route the comparison by hooks that allow virtual subclassing.